# Processing cannot install

Tags: python, pip, processing

When I try to run the command:

```
pip install processing
```

on cmd, this apears:

```
Collecting processing
  Using cached processing-0.52.zip (178 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [7 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h2338we4\processing_12fe334ab1d94cd8b8050ff7aa113907\setup.py", line 12
          raise ValueError, 'Versions of Python before 2.4 are not supported'
                          ^
      SyntaxError: invalid syntax
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I noticed that it tells me that `Versions of Python before 2.4 are not supported`, but my python version is 3.11:

```
Python 3.11.0 (main, Oct 24 2022, 18:26:48) [MSC v.1933 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: What version is `pip`?  Could you run `pip3` instead?

Comment: Same error with pip3.

Comment: Can you update your question to include that error message?

Comment: This is the error message. After ```on cmd this apears:```

Comment: If you mean the ```pip3``` error message, is  exacly the same.

Comment: This library is *ancient*.  I tried this myself locally and got the same error.  It isn't the case that *your* code isn't working, it's the *installation* that isn't working.  There's a straight-up ancient Python 2.x bug in this installer.  So I don't think you're going to be able to install this dependency in your environment.

Comment: You want https://github.com/jdf/processing.py (as linked from the processing.org website), not this.

Answer (score 1):

As Makoto already mentioned, it appears the processing pipy project is out of data.

You can try the official [Processing Python Mode](https://py.processing.org/) from the Processing's IDE by pressing the Java button on the top right side, then **Add Mode > Python Mode**.

An interesting alternative is [py5](https://py5coding.org/) (which also supports jupyter notebooks).

Other alternatives that I'm aware of include:

- [processing_py](https://pypi.org/project/processing-py/)
- [NodeBox](https://www.nodebox.net/)
- [Field](http://openendedgroup.com/field2/)